# Show correct price based on quantity picked from select menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calculated-field

I have these two fields inside form:

```
<form method="post" action="./completed-order.php">

<input value="0.025" name="price" type="hidden" />

<select name="quantity" id="selectQuantity" tabindex="1" class="span2">
<option value="3000">3000</option>
<option value="4000">4000</option>
<option value="5000">5000</option>
<option value="6000">6000</option>
<option value="7000">7000</option>
<option value="8000">8000</option>
<option value="9000">9000</option>
<option value="10000">10000</option>
<option value="11000">11000</option>
........
</select>

<input value="" name="final-price" type="text" />

</form>
```

what I want to that when user select any givven values from select menu, to multiply that value with price value from name="price" field and show it inside name="final-price" field. I need this to be done using jQuery.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I dont have any code since I dont know JQquery very good so I asked someone to write it here for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of this would work:

```
var quantity = $('#selectQuantity').find(":selected").val();
var price = $('input[name="price"]').val();

$('input[name="final-price"').val(quantity * price);
```

To get this to update every time you need to hook the `selectQuantiy` list changing using `change()`

```
$('#selectQuantity').change(function() {
    var quantity = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var price = $('input[name="price"]').val();

    $('input[name="final-price"').val(quantity * price);
});
```

Comment: thanks, its working but I have small problem, when the page opens up it shows the right price with default selected value from select menu, but when I select another value it does not update the "final-price" field but it shows the first value. How to make it updates whenever I pick new value? Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, working. Once last change I need. When page loads up, the "final-price" field is empty and it only shows price when I pick value from "quantity" select menu, however I need to it show the price of first value multiplied with the value from "price" field, can you make that change too keeping these that you already wrote? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm sure you could figure that out by combining the two answers or looking up how to define a function in javascript, calling that function on page load and on the .change()

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var xFinalPrice = $('input[name="final-price"]');
var xQty = $('input[name="quantity"]');
var xPrice = $('input[name="price"]');

xFinalPrice.val(parseInt(xQty.val()) * parseInt(xPrice.val()));
```

Comment: seems like its not working, it shows NaN value inside "final-price" input field.

Comment: @Rajaprabhu it looks like the price field is using a decimal, I guess `parseInt()` fails on that!